# Objective-C How to print NSSet on one line (no trailing comma / space)

Tags: objective-c

Im trying to print out an NSSet on a single line, comma separation but no trailing comma or space. how can i do this?

i know that this works for an array:

```
    NSMutableString *outputStringArray = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    NSMutableArray *myArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

    for (int k = 0; k < [myArray count]; k++) {
        [outputStringArray appendFormat:@"%@, ", [myArray objectAtIndex:k]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", [outputStringArray substringToIndex:[outputStringArray length] - 2]);
```

but since sets don't have indexing i cant do this.

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can always make an array out of a set, like this:

```
NSArray *myArray = [mySet allObjects];
```

After that, you can get your string with `componentsJoinedByString:`:

```
NSString *str = [myArray componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

Of course you can achieve the same effect with a simple loop similar to the one in your post:

```
BOOL isFirst = YES;
for (id element in mySet) {
    if (!isFirst) {
        [outputStringArray appendString:@", "];
    } else {
        isFirst = NO;
    }
    [outputStringArray appendFormat:@"%@", element];
}
```

Comment: Using your loop there isn't a comma between the first and second element with building the string.

Comment: @aqua Did you try it? It should be there.

Answer (score 7):

Get the objects in your set as an array and use `componentsJoinedByString:`

```
NSSet *myset = ....;
NSString *joinedString = [[myset allObjects] componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```